# Matlab Coder force boolean_T to be native C99 bool type

Tags: matlab, matlab-coder, embedded-coder

How can I force matlab embedded coder to set "boolean_T" as "bool" C99 type?

Without that, I need explicit cast conversion I/O signals mapping for int->boolean_t (not needed for int->bool).

Answer (score 1):

Switch up the hardware to something other than `Generic->MATLAB Host Computer` and you should get `bool` for C99:

```matlab
cfg = coder.config('lib');
% Hit TAB to see other possible hardware or do
%   open cfg
% and use the GUI to pick one
cfg.HardwareImplementation.ProdHWDeviceType = 'Intel->x86-64 (Linux 64)';
codegen f -args true -config cfg -report -std:c99
```

With MATLAB Host Computer, `boolean_T` is preserved in case some MATLAB libraries are pulled in to ensure binary compatibility.